# Wordpress cPanel Redirect to another site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In my Wordpress installation I have 3 sites: `/blog/`, `/blog/en`, `/blog/pt`.
I want it so, that whenever someone accesses `/blog/`, they will get redirected to `/blog/pt`.

I've already tried to create a Redirect inside my cPanel, but it's not working.
I've done it like this:

Domain to Redirect: `mysite.com/blog/`

Site to Redirect to: `mysite.com/blog/pt`.

But it's not working. Any ideas? I can probably do this with the .htaccess, but I don't understand any of it..

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog /blog/pt
```

Comment: Adam, Do you have 3 wordpress installations or just 1 wordpress installation with multi-site?

Comment: @SiyamKumar I have one wordpress installation with multi-site

Comment: If multi-site is enabled, easy way to do is using plugins. I would recommend this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the following on your .htaccess file to achieve the redirection you want.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog /blog/pt
```

Comment: Good Idea, but now I'm getting the `redirected you too many times.` error. I'm putting this in the .htaccess at the root of the wordpress installation.

Comment: Are you getting too many redirection error on the whole website or just on the blog page? Is there any other redirection rule you set on your .htaccess? Can you provide your current .htaccess content.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my question with it. It's on the whole website

Comment: Can you remove the following from you htaccess and check .
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: Is the redirection you set from cpanel still exists? If you could provide full details I might help with the solution.

Comment: No, I already removed that redirection. I don't know which more information I could give you that could help..

Comment: If you could provide the domain I could check to which URL it is redirecting to and figure out where to look for solution.